# GWT- In celltable column checkboxcell select all records i want select display record

Tags: gwt

Frineds,

I am using celltable and their is one column which I put in table header for select all record option and also I am using pager which showing max 15 record in one page. when I clicked on selectall option it will select all records which are present page no 2,3,4,.... in short all records get selected(if total records is 100 it's selected 100 records).so i want only select display page records not  all...
ref code is  -

```
      final SelectionModel < GenericFirewallRule > selectionModel = 
new MultiSelectionModel < GenericFirewallRule > ();
            deleteRuleCellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel,DefaultSelectionEventManager. < GenericFirewallRule > createCheckboxManager());
    //      CheckboxCell cbForHeader = new CheckboxCell();

    Column < GenericFirewallRule, Boolean > checkColumn = new Column < GenericFirewallRule, Boolean > (
    new CheckboxCell()) {@Override
        public Boolean getValue(GenericFirewallRule object) {

            if(object == null || object.getRuleNumber() == null){
                   return null;
            }else{
            if (selectionModel.isSelected(object)) {
                if (!ruleListForDelete.contains(object)) {
                    ruleListForDelete.add(object);
                }
            } else {
                if (ruleListForDelete.contains(object)) {
                    ruleListForDelete.remove(object);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("ruleListForDelete : " + ruleListForDelete);
            return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
            }
        }
    };
```

Please suggest me solutions....

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
selectAllHeader = new Header<Boolean>(new HeaderCheckbox()) {

    @Override
    public Boolean getValue() {
        for (T item : getVisibleItems()) {
            if (!getSelectionModel().isSelected(item)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return getVisibleItems().size() > 0;
    }
};

selectAllHeader.setUpdater(new ValueUpdater<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void update(Boolean value) {
        for (T object : getVisibleItems()) {
            getSelectionModel().setSelected(object, value);
        }
    }

});

public class HeaderCheckbox extends CheckboxCell {

    private final SafeHtml INPUT_CHECKED = SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\" checked/>");
    private final SafeHtml INPUT_UNCHECKED = SafeHtmlUtils.fromSafeConstant("<input type=\"checkbox\" tabindex=\"-1\"/>");

    public HeaderCheckbox() {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, Boolean value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
      if (value != null && value) {
        sb.append(INPUT_CHECKED);
      } else {
        sb.append(INPUT_UNCHECKED);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to show that you can use `getVisibleItems()` to solve your problem. I added HeaderCheckbox class code for you if you want to use it as is.